# Resizing div with click?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2008

I have a `webform` that looks like this. It's a `div` in a `masterpage` that contains several `GridViews`:

[image]

As you can see, the gridviews take up much of the space, so I would like to minimize them. I don't want to use a `CollapsiblePanel` because it will hide everything. I would like to hide half of the div/gridviews; something like this:
[image]

Basically, I want to add a control that I can click: when expanded, it will display the full height of the gridview. When collapsed, I will only see a fracion of the `div`and the gridviews.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all the GridViews inside a div with a class that specifies the height and hides the overflow. Then when you click the button it changes the class of the class of `gridViewContainer` with the height set to `auto`.

```
<div class="small" id="gridViewContainer">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="toggleGridContent()" value="toggleGridContent" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleGridContent() {
        var id = "#gridViewContainer";
        if ($(id).hasClass("small")) {
            $(id).attr("class", "large");
        } else {
            $(id).attr("class", "small");
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .small {
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .large {
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax Control Toolkit CollapsiblePanel does have CollapsedSize/ExpandedSize properties if that's what you're using?

Javascripters would do it clientside with e.g. jQuery. In fact, unless you can find an out of the box aspx control, clientside is much easier that ACT controls. 
Something like

```html
<!-- give your divs a class and collapsed/expanded sizes -->
<div class="collapsibleDiv" CollapsedSize="10" ExpandedSize="300"
  style="border: 1px red dashed;"
  >
  <p>-</p>
  ...
  <p>-</p>
</div>


<!-- bottom of page -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
  $(".collapsibleDiv").click(
    function() {
      var me = $(this);
      var expandHeight= Number(me.attr('ExpandedSize'))
      var collapseHeight=Number(me.attr('CollapsedSize'));
      var isExpanded= me.height()===expandHeight;
      var targetHeight= isExpanded ? collapseHeight : expandHeight;
      me.animate({ height: targetHeight});
      //or without animation : me.height(targetHeight)
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution, and I see that the div can be resized, but the gridview is never hidden. It's as if the gridview's outside the div.

Comment: I ended up using the Ajax Control Toolkit CollapsiblePanel. I didn't know it had the CollapsedSize/ExpandedSize properties. Thanks.